# spring mvc charset

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, character-encoding

I am using spring mvc. I am writing in Hebrew so in my jsp form I ask the user to give his name in Hebrew. Here is the form:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<form:form method="post" action="registration-submit.html">
    אנא מלא את הפרטים הבאים בכדי להשלים את הרשמתך:
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>שם:</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" type="text" id="nameInput"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>סיסמא:</td>
            <td><form:input path="password" type="password" id="passwordInput"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>וידוא סיסמא:</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="passwordVerifyInput"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>דואר אלקטרוני:</td>
            <td><form:input path="email" type="text" id="emailInput"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="הירשם"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

For `registration-submit.html` I have the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration-submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView showRegistrationSubmitPage(
            @ModelAttribute("registrationForm") final RegistrationForm registrationForm,
            BindingResult result) {
                ...
                ...
}
```

When I add `registrationForm.name` to the watch, I see: × ×××¨ (unreadable characters) instead of the Hebrew name.
The jsp file is saved with UTF-8 charset. Why do I get unreadable characters from the form? How can I set the charset of spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try registering a [`CharacterEncodingFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html) in web.xml

Comment: And make sure it's the first filter activated

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this

```
 <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name> 

 <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class> 

 <init-param> 

    <param-name>encoding</param-name> 

    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value> 

 </init-param> 

 <init-param> 

    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name> 

    <param-value>true</param-value> 

 </init-param>
```

```
 <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name> 

<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: make sure it's the first filter